# "Which one" usage for people

Tags: grammar, wh-questions

Can I use "Which one?" for people like we use it for things. See the following conversation.

> A: I want to talk to your daughter.

> B: Which one? The fat one or the thin one?

I googled it and found many examples that it can be used for people. Is it correct (At least in informal situation)? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly you can use it for people.

Comment: @Kate Bunting thanks. Normally, I have learnt that 'which' is used for things only. So I got confused.

Comment: Yes, it's _the thing which_ and _the person who_ - but this doesn't apply when _which?_ is a question.

Comment: Nice people might say 'the big one or the thin one'.